# Should I ask a question to ask guide for buying a new bike?

Tags: discussion, product-rec

Should I ask a question to ask guide for buying a new bike?

[How to select an inexpensive road bike for a heavier rider?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/should-i-buy-this-bike-for-myself)

I asked this question and it down ranked. I just wondered if it's out of context so what the site is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Bicycles!

I see from your profile that you've used [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) a fair amount, but haven't much used any of the sites that have had shopping recommendation question problems.

I commented on you question before I saw this question.

Here's a blog post one of the heads of Stack Exchange wrote about this problem: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

I see some basic problems with your question:

1. It has a very limited lifespan (when they change to next year's model in a month the question and its answers won't be useful to anybody)
2. A "yes" or "no" doesn't really teach anybody anything
3. You don't have quite enough details in the question. What kind of rider are you? Where will you be riding? What kind of surfaces, distance, terrain, etc?
4. It sounds like you're trying to do mail-order bicycle purchasing which is notoriously tricky. We're usually recommending people go to a local bike shop where they can try the bikes out. Just your height isn't enough to be sure you're getting the right size bike.

Basically, it's better to ask what to look for than to ask about a specific bike.

Here's a somewhat better example of somebody asking a similar type of question: [What bike+equipment for a long daily urban commute?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/what-bikeequipment-for-a-long-daily-urban-commute) (look in the comments, there's a lot of details asked about)

Comment: it's possible we could create a canonical "how do I decide which bike to buy?" question answer pair -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/